# DateTime XAML Binding String Format to show "null" for DateTime.MinValue

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a binding to a date:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=EndDateTime, StringFormat=d}"/>
```

What I want is that when its value is `DateTime.MinValue` (DateTime's default value) to display null instead of the date.

Is this possible **without** using a converter, simply by somehow extending my binding's `StringFormat` property?

Is there any other **XAML only** solution?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: can you change type of `EndDateTime` to `DateTime?` ?

Comment: @BalaR It is DateTime. EndDateTime is the name of a property in my object.

Comment: yeah! DateTime is a struct and cannot be null. Can you change it to a nullable type? `DateTime?` or `Nullable<DateTime>` ?

Comment: oops sorry I didn't see the ? after DateTime :) Unfortunately I cannot change it to a nullable one...

Comment: Why can't you change the type to a Nullable<DateTime>? I appreciate your Model may be constrained to using a DateTime but in your ViewModel just expose this as null if the Model has DateTime.MinValue;

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could use a DataTrigger in the TextBlock's Style

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=EndDateTime, StringFormat=d}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding EndDateTime}" Value="{x:Static sys:DateTime.MinValue}">
                    <Setter Property="Text" Value="NULL" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Good point - obviously you can see I had Silverlight on the mind. ;]

Comment: this code is not working for me. the date which i have updated during runtime it's not updated to the control

Comment: Don't forget to add namespace: `xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"`

Answer (score 0):

There is no XAML only solution for this in Silverlight 4.  In Silverlight 5 you could use a Markup Extension, though that's still code you would have to write.  In Silverlight 4 you could use a Behavior as well.

My suggestion is to expose a property on your ViewModel which provides the null functionality.  Then you wouldn't have to use a Converter, though the property you're binding to would work as you would like.